# How can I build an array from attributes in multiple html lists?

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, html-lists

I'm trying to get multiple attributes from unordered lists from multiple divs that look like this:

```
    <div class="graph" style="display:none;">
        <ul g-max='10'>
            <li g-color='green' g-val='4'></li>
            <li g-color='blue' g-val='3.6'></li>
            <li g-color='red' g-val='8'></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="graph" style="display:none;">
        <ul g-max='14'>
            <li g-color='green' g-val='2'></li>
            <li g-color='blue' g-val='9'></li>
            <li g-color='red' g-val='3.98'></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to do this with jQuery and I'm using the following:

```
    var graph_array = [];

    $('.graph').each(function(divind)
    {
          $('ul').each(function(ulind)
          {
               $('li').each(function(liind)
               {
                     graph_array[divind][ulind][liind]['g-val'] = $(this).attr('g-val');
                     graph_array[divind][ulind][liind]['g-color'] = $(this).attr('g-color');
               });
          });
    });
    alert(graph_array);
```

But, even when I move things around and try different techniques like `.map()` or `.toArray()`, nothing works. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm wanting to have an ending result that'll look like this:

```
    [{
       {
         {g-color:green, g-val:4},{g-color:blue, g-val:3.6},{g-color:red, g-val:8}
       },
       {
         {g-color:green, g-val:2},{g-color:blue, g-val:9},{g-color:red, g-val:3.98}
       }
    }]
```

Comment: Can you show the array/object you want to end up with?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you hope to have at the end, but I will say this: when you say `$('li').each`, it's going to loop through every `li` on the page -- not just the ones that are inside the `ul` that the parent loop is referencing.  Perhaps you want something like `$(li, ulind).each`, which would constrain the selector to the given context.  (And you would need to do this at each level, of course.)

Comment: it would help if you add desired output..

Comment: I added a desired array output above. Thanks!

Comment: Woah, not legal! What about `[ {green:4, blue:3.6, red:8}, {green:2, blue:9, red:3.98} ];`, or similar. This is legal js, and contains all the data available.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot sorry. I couldn't remember the layout of the `[]` and the `{}`

Comment: Cool! You've got at least one good answer below anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to look out for here is that you did not initialize the arrays you were trying to append to. You'll need to initialize an array for each group.
Another thing to do here is utilize the scope of the `each` function and one of its two parameters.

```
$.each($(element_array),function(index,elem){
  // $(this)
  // $(elem) 
});
```

I've listed two interchangeable ways you can use the scope of the `each` and also utilize the `this` keyword. When you are in each iteration of the `each` loop, the current item can be found in the `$(this)` variable. You could also use `$(elem)`.

In cases where you have nested `each` commands, I find it better to use a different variable for each nested loop and not use `this`. I find it less confusing.

So basically what you need to do is use the relative current variable to search within its decedents.

```
var graph_array = [];

$('.graph').each(function(divIndex,currentDiv) {
  if (graph_array[divIndex] == undefined){ graph_array[divIndex] = []; }
  $(currentDiv).find('ul').each(function(ulIndex,currentUl) {
    if (graph_array[divIndex][ulIndex] == undefined){ graph_array[divIndex][ulIndex] = []; }
    $(currentUl).find('li').each(function(liIndex,currentLi) {
      if (graph_array[divIndex][ulIndex][liIndex] == undefined){ graph_array[divIndex][ulIndex][liIndex] = []; }     
      graph_array[divIndex][ulIndex][liIndex]['g-val'] = $(currentLi).attr('g-val');
      graph_array[divIndex][ulIndex][liIndex]['g-color'] = $(currentLi).attr('g-color');
    });
  });
});

console.log(graph_array);​
```

#### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GG4uy/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the arrays or pre-populate them.  Like this, for example:

```
var graph_array = [];
$('.graph').each(function(divind, e)
{
      $(e).find('ul').each(function(ulind, e)
      {
           $(e).find('li').each(function(liind, e)
           {
               // create level 1 sub-array, or use existing
               var level1 = (graph_array[divind] || (graph_array[divind] = []));

               // create or re-use level #2 sub-array
               var level2 = (level1[ulind] || (level1[ulind] = []));

               // create a property map
               var map = (level2[liind] = {});
               map ['g-val'] = $(e).attr('g-val');
               map ['g-color'] = $(e).attr('g-color');
           });
      });
});
// display as a string
alert(JSON.stringify(graph_array));​
```

See here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q57W5/5/

Comment: Nice! This works well. But, I noticed that you said that I should assume two arrays. Is there I a way to make it to take any amount of different `div`s? I'm wanting to make it a little more versatile so that it'll recognize all `div`s with the `.graph` class.

Comment: @Cod-nerd I realized that would be better, after I posted -- see my edited answer.

Comment: I've tried this on your jsfiddle link and it works great, but it fails on my own page. I looked through the jquery and I'm not recognizing `stringify`. Is this relative jsfiddle or a specific package?

Comment: @Cod-nerd JSON.stringify it standard as of Javascript 1.7: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @Cod-nerd here's the browser support for it ... IE7 and below does not support it.  http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: I'm going to update the jquery file that I'm using. Hopefully, this will fix the problem.

Comment: I liked the output that yours provided on jsfiddle, but I couldn't get it to work on my page. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:-

```
var graphArray = new Array();
$(".graph ul li").each(function(i) {
    graphArray[i] = $(this).attr("g-color") + ":" + $(this).attr("g-val");
});

alert(graphArray);
```